# Why is this Viburnum farreri dying?

Tags: shrubs, outdoor

We have several Viburnum farreri in our garden. Last year one out of seven died, but we thought it was because of the heat/dryness.

This year another one has just died, but I don't think it has been very dry.

It has this weird white goo on the leaves, but I don't know if that is related.

1
[image: plant]
2
[image: plant]
3
[image: plant]
4
[image: plant]

A neighboring bush has lice on the underside of the leaves as well as ants "milking" the lice:

[image: ants and lice]

Here is the currently "healthy" neighboring plant (5 meters away), same plant as above

[image: undead]

Location: Southern Sweden

What is killing these plants?

Answer (score 2):

Your neighbour's plant has an insect infestation - it might be aphids, specifically black fly, but it's hard to tell from the photo. Treatment is with a suitable insecticidal spray, preferably a  systemic one, not a contact one, and all parts should be sprayed, including beneath all leaves as well as the tops.

As for your plants, the 'white stuff' is significant - I am not 100% sure what is. I would suggest scraping off some of it from the bark/stems to see what, if anything, is inside the deposits - it might be scale insect or a fungal problem. Did you notice any toadstool/mushroom growths near it at any time, or are there any soft or soggy areas in the woody stems?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After closer inspection I now believe the white stuff is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icerya_purchasi

Answer (score 1):

After reading user Bamboo's answer (white stuff => fungal) I dare to suggest
[Downy Mildew (Plasmopara viburni)](https://www.ipmimages.org/browse/detail.cfm?imgnum=5458711)

> This disease first appears as light green spots on the upper leaf
> surfaces. The dots grow to create angular patches between the leaf
> veins. Downy **greyish-white** fungal growth forms on the undersides of
> the leaves.
>
> Downy mildew illness differs from powdery mildew in that the fungal
> growth **is seen on the bottom rather than the upper leaf surface**.

From [this source](https://gardenwisper.com/how-to-identify-and-treat-common-viburnum-diseases/) (emphasis mine)

If your spring has been cold and wet also consider
[Viburnum-Bacterial Blight](https://pnwhandbooks.org/plantdisease/host-disease/viburnum-bacterial-blight)

> Symptoms Spots are at first water soaked, then turn brown and
> irregular in shape. Oregon observations are that spots may be angular.
> Margins frequently develop a bacterial exudate. Numerous spots during
> early shoot growth can deform leaves. Stem lesions are elongate and
> generally not as obvious. Severe infections can result in a shoot
> dieback.

Perhaps you have access to a microscope and can examine the white stuff further.

Comment: Downy mildew is a possiblity, but I ruled it out because these deposits are on stems/bark as well, putting me in mind of woolly aphid, which occurs on apple trees.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After closer inspection I now believe the white stuff is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icerya_purchasi